# Ignite compute grid job coordinate/invoke

Tags: ignite

I am new to Ignite and looking at compute grid, sounds like something we can use, i have compute job (same job but on different segment of data), i can have multiple jobs to run on multiple nodes. My question is there is only one node that will call the job execution (thus pass to one of the nodes), how can i determine/set thus only one node will do this coordination?

Thanks
Shannon

Comment: Can i use https://apacheignite.readme.io/v1.0/docs/cluster-singletons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cluster singletons, but you also do not have to care about coordination. Ignite cluster will handle most of cases of compute failover automatically.

Comment: Thanks. what i meant is that i have a job to kick off this computation at an interval, i need to use the clulster singleton to make sure only one such job is running. Or there is a better/easy way to do that?

Comment: @ShannonMa You can also try and use `ignite-schedule`, but cluster singleton service is actually trivial to setup.